# sql query to format the parent child in a hierarchical list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have the data displayed in the below parent child like relationship, where the first row should be parent row, and every subsequent row should be for child with null in all parent specific columns. [image]

[![Here is the example][2]][2]

In the above the consumer 99999999 has 2 dependents 22222222 and 33333333.

I tried doing this with Lead and lag but that will need an order by in the CTE. 
I was thinking of looking at the previous ApplicationroductID, and would flag whenever I see that it has changed. So by doing that my I can flag the parent and Child. 
I could potentially get away with the order by problem by using a temp table, but that doesnt sound like a very good solution. 
*Is there a better way of doing this that you guys can think of. I want to have the data to be in the above format.*

```
select 
de.ID as ConsumerID
,dd.ID as DependentID,
f.ApplicationroductID,
LEAD(f.ApplicationroductID) OVER (Order by fep.ApplicationroductID) Lead,
LAG(f.ApplicationroductID) OVER (Order by fep.ApplicationroductID) Lag 
 from Fact f
INNER JOIN DimEmp de ON fep.DimEmp_FK = de.ID
INNER JOIN DimDep dd ON fep.DimDep_FK = dd.ID
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? mysql, oracle, and sql server are all different products. Also, a CTE is not a temp table.

Comment: @JNveill Edited with more details. Its Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        de.ID as ConsumerID,
        null  as DependentID,
        de.ConsumerName,
        null  as ParticipantName,
        f.ApplicationroductID
     from Fact f
    INNER JOIN DimEmp de ON f.DimEmp_FK = de.ID

    union

    select 
        de.ID as ConsumerID,
        dd.ID as DependentID,
        null  as ConsumerName,
        dd.ParticipantName,
        f.ApplicationroductID
     from Fact f
    INNER JOIN DimEmp de ON f.DimEmp_FK = de.ID
    INNER JOIN DimDep dd ON f.DimDep_FK = dd.ID
)
select case
        when DependentID is null then ConsumerID
        else null
       end as ConsumerID,
       DependentID,
       ConsumerName,
       ParticipantName,
       ApplicationroductID
  from cte
 order by ConsumerId,
          DependentId
```

The two SELECTS + UNION will get you all rows, with NULL or real value for each row type. We get the ConsumerId in both SELECTs in order to use it in the outer SELECT's ORDER BY expression. The outer SELECT switches NULL or ConsumerId, depending on the row type.

Comment: Thanks your solution will work, but imagine if there are more Dependent attribute that we want to hide for Consumer like DependetFirstName, LastName etc. It will require a lot of case statements. This will not be very efficient. In my actual solution I have now 15 case statements and query is very slow with just 3 joins.

Comment: Good point concerning maintenance but performance is not an issue with these simple CASEs.